# R o R (Discrete Mathematics - Relations on Sets)

Tags: set, tuples, relation, discrete-mathematics

The following is given

```
Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Let R = the relation on the set A, or: 
R = {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (3,2), (3,3), (4,4)}

Find R o R as a set of tuples.
```

I am not certain how to approach this problem.
My best guess is

```
R o R = {((1,1),(1,1)), ((1,1),(1,2), ..., ((4,4),(4,4))}
```

but that does not seem right to me. I'm looking for how to solve this type of problem, not just a solution to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Definition 6 from [Chapter 8:Relations and Thier Properties](http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C251/html/chapter8.htm) :

```
S ○ R 

Composite relation of R and S where

    R from A to B

    S from B to C

is the ordered pairs:

    (a, c), where a ∈ A and c ∈ C

for which b ∈ B such that

    (a, b) ∈ R ^ (b, c) ∈ S

(a, c) ∈ S ○ R if (a, b) ∈ R ^ (b, c) ∈ S
```

and using example that follows it, one can get[image]

So the final answer is

R ○ R = {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (4,4)}